# Double Aggregate Function Mysql

Tags: mysql, count, sum

I want to take the maximum value from a series of returned values but I can't figure out a simple way to do it. My query returns all rows so 1/2 way there. I can filter it down with PHP but I'd like to do it all in SQL. I tried with a `max` subquery but that returned all results still.

**DDL**:

```
create table matrix(
   count int(4), 
   date date, 
   product int(4)
);
create table products(
   id int(4), 
   section int(4)
);
```

**DML**:

```
select max(magic_count), section, id
from (
    select sum(count) as magic_count, p.section, p.id
    from matrix as m
    join products as p on m.product = p.id
    group by m.product
) as faketable
group by id, section
```

[Demo with my current try.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bda6f8f/6)

Only ids `1` and `3` should be returned from the sample data because they have the highest cumulative `count` for each of the `section`s.

[Here's a second SQL fiddle that demonstrates the same issue.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cd3af/5)

Comment: `SELECT sum(count) as magic_count, p.section, p.id
FROM matrix as m
join products as p
on m.product = p.id
group by m.product`  You don't have aggregation over p.id. Let me guess MySQL lower than 5.8 without `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` mode?

Comment: @LukaszSzozda Yes, you are correct. This is being run on `5.6.35`. There only is one `p.id` record. Aggregating won't do anything in that case, right? I group by the `m.product` because there are multiple `m.product` rows.

Comment: I don't like the idea of non-agg cols. But anyway [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bda6f8f/23/0)

Comment: @LukaszSzozda I extended the data set, that only brings back 1 result http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cd3af/4 vs. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cd3af/5

Comment: Read an intro to group by so you know how it works. Which is the query you mean by "My query returns all rows "? Also your code suggests you do not want "the maximum value from a series of returned values", so please express what you do want clearly enough that someone could code your query & relate to example input & output. A [mcve] includes a clear specification. Please edit clarifications into your question, not comments.

Comment: @philipxy How is this not minimal? There is only 1 query in the question, there is a link to SQL fiddle showing it. The statement refers to the 1 query. Can you please explain what part of the `group by` you think I don't understand?

Comment: I didn't say it wasn't minimal. Please address my last comment. (Which might have been edited since you saw it.)

Comment: @philipxy `Please edit clarifications into your question, not comments.`? There is nothing I see that needs clarifying. Can you please just say what you want fixed?

Comment: You have made clarifying comments whose content is not edited into your question. Also, I clearly asked for other clarifications. You don't appear to be putting much effort into understanding or addressing my comments.

Comment: @philipxy Nothing I've said in the comments is not in my question. The links are to a larger data set (which isn't needed and might be construed as non-minimal). The issue is reproducible with the data I initially provided. If you don't want to help just go to another question. If you want to help great, please state what you are asking. If it is what I want I think the last sentence of my question states that already.

Comment: @user3783243 If you are interested in performance, you should check out demos I posted, which contain 20K rows. There you can compare performance of both queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
select a.id, 
       a.section,
       a.magic_count
from (
    select p.id,
           p.section,
           magic_count
    from (
        select m.product, sum(count) as magic_count
        from matrix m
        group by m.product
    ) sm
    join products p on sm.product = p.id
) a
left join (
    select p.id,
           p.section,
           magic_count
    from (
        select m.product, sum(count) as magic_count
        from matrix m
        group by m.product
    ) sm
    join products p on sm.product = p.id
) b on a.section = b.section and a.magic_count < b.magic_count
where b.id is null
```

- see a simplified example (and other methods) in the manual entry for [The Rows Holding the Group-wise Maximum of a Certain Column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html)
- see it working live [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cd3af/15/0)

Answer (score 1):

Here you have solution without using `JOIN`s, it has better performance than the other answer, which uses lot of `JOIN`s:

```
select @rn := 1, @sectionLag := 0;

select id, section, count from (
    select id,
           case when @sectionLag = section then @rn := @rn + 1 else @rn := 1 end rn,
           @sectionLag := section,
           section, 
           count
    from (
        select id, section, sum(count) count
        from matrix m
        join products p on m.product = p.id
        group by id, section
    ) a order by section, count desc
) a where rn = 1
```

Variables at the beginning are used to imitate window functions (`LAG` and `ROW_NUMBER`), which are available in MySQL 8.0 or higher (if you are using such version, let me know, so I will give you solution also with window functions).

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7ce1b/20)

[Another demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5Wmfh9EENHf8zpuSu17gvn/1), where you can compare performance of my and the other query. It contains ~20K rows and my query tends to be almost 2 times faster.

Comment: Joins don't necessarily make a query slow, and having the same subquery multiple times in a query doesn't mean it's executed multiple times. So please be careful with overgeneralized statements like "my performance is better". When you haven't measured, you can't really know. And queries that make use of variables can easily have worse performance *in general*, because they often result in full table scans. That's not the case with your query though.

Comment: @fancyPants Your query uses lots of joins, so at least there's strong suspicion, that my query will have better performance. You're right, I didn't measure it, shame on me :) My query doesn't require anything but ordering of a table, that's it. Thanks for remarks though :)

Comment: @fancyPants Checked with some sample data (small amount of records though), my query **always** takes less to execute. [See example](https://www.db-fiddle.com/) - your query  1ms, mine - 0ms.

Comment: Again, joining is usually not a problem. Ordering a table can be, though. Especially a temporary table. And benchmarking with small amounts of sample data (and in sqlfiddle?) is just ridiculous.

Comment: @fancyPants With 5K rows it's still faster. [See example](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5Wmfh9EENHf8zpuSu17gvn/0). Data about times should come from db engine, not including time of sending data over the internet.

Comment: I don't know how sqlfiddle handles this, but usually the time to send a result to a client is included. Whatever, maybe it is faster...

Comment: @fancyPants Finishing our dispute, if it takes sending result time into accout, it should be the same time for both queries anyway, so it is only matter of performance to make the difference. Additionally, query is simplier and easier to read and maintain :)

Comment: That's a matter of opinion / personal preference.

Comment: I've benchmarked with the actual tables (matrix 8.8 million, products 70,000). The results were very close. This answer executed in `13 rows in set (9.44 sec)` vs. `13 rows in set (10.19 sec)`. I had to modify `@sectionLag := 0;` to `@sectionLag := -1;` because `0` is a valid section for us.